# Would it be considered controversial to describe a character in my script as "black"?

Tags: word-usage, politeness

Don't know if this is the wrong forum for this. I'm writing a script and I have described a character in it as "a tall black dude". Would that be considered controversial in the US?

Comment: This is not an English grammar question. If anything, it is an etiquette question, but the answer would be opinion-based.

Comment: Is the characters colour in some way pertinent to the story?

Comment: @Astralbee It's totally a grammar question. It's the sort of thing defined in publication style guides, for instance.

Comment: It is not a grammar question.  It would also be correct grammar to say "a tall colored person".  It is not a matter of grammar, but of etiquette.

Comment: @JamesK Because this is the ELL StackExchange, I feel obligated to correct you, lest some poor ELL be lead astray: the correct term to use is "Person of Color", not "coloured person".

Comment: That is indeed a much more polite term. However the expression "colored person" is correct grammar.  There are lots more rude, racist and insulting expressions that are perfectly correct grammar.

Comment: This depends on when and where teh story is set. And this question really belongs on Writing.se, not ELL.SE

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because It should be migrated to Writing.SE.

Comment: @nick012000 I disagree, but at the very least it isn't suitable for this site. Let's just say that someone says it's okay to call someone 'black' in the USA but not in Britain. Here we can answer questions about the *grammatical* differences between different dialects of English, but we don't comment on *cultural* differences.

Comment: @Astralbee If there's a difference between American English and British English on this subject, write an answer detailing that rather than complaining in the comments. Differences between the two main dialects can be rather significant, and are valuable information for English language learners.

Comment: @nick012000 You misunderstand me. I won't write an answer on this occasion because I believe the question is off-topic, and I'm not alone - we're currently one vote away from closing the question. For clarity, I **don't** believe there is a difference in AmEng and BrEng on this - in both dialects "a black man" would mean precisely the same thing. This is a question of *etiquette* - is it okay to say it? And that might be different between British and American *cultures* but not language.

Comment: @Astralbee I don't believe that this is an etiquette question at all. It's a question about the correct words to use, and that's something that can be objectively answered.

Comment: @nick012000 *Culturally* "correct", not grammatically correct.

Comment: @Astralbee No, *politically* correct, and that's the same for every Anglophone culture where left-wing politics exists (which is basically all of them). It transcends mere etiquette and culture, and is a matter of life and death when you consider the prospect of getting fired for using incorrect language.

Comment: @nick012000 Okay, call it political correctness if you like, that's still opinion-based and off-topic on this site. But all countries contain different cultures *and* different politics. I'd like to see you walk down Dalberg Road in Brixton and ask people if you can call them black with a capital B, see how long you survive.

Comment: @Astralbee If that difference exists, it's a difference between the dialects, and deserves its own answer. It has nothing to do with differences in etiquette, but entirely due to differences in dialect.

Answer (score 3):

#### Black should be capitalized, but it would otherwise be fine.

When used to describe Americans of African descent, "Black" is not just an acceptable term to describe them with, but is is in fact the preferred term - but when doing so, it should be capitalized.

To quote the [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/07/05/insider/capitalized-black.html), in a recent article they published regarding a change in their policy on the matter:

> Decades later, a monthlong internal discussion at The Times led the paper on Tuesday to make, for similar reasons, its latest style change on race — capitalizing Black when describing people and cultures of African origin.

> “We believe this style best conveys elements of shared history and identity, and reflects our goal to be respectful of all the people and communities we cover,” said Dean Baquet, The Times’s executive editor, and Phil Corbett, associate managing editor for standards, in a memo to staff.

Comment: +1. I am of the opinion that this question is a word usage question. One minor thing with your answer is that one of the reasons "Black" is quickly becoming the preferred term is that it transcends and subsumes other terms such as "African American". "Black" is more than "African American".It is greater and more universal.

Comment: I don't claim to speak for all black (or Black) people, but I don't think a newspaper style-guide gets to determine what they want to be called. Even the mighty NY Times with its mainly affluent, over 50, white readership. This would be a great answer to the question "should 'black' have a capital B" but sadly the question was "would it be controversial".

Comment: @Astralbee The newspaper updated their style guide after consulting with them over their preferred nomenclature.

Comment: @nick012000 "Them". Could this get any more offensive?

Comment: @Astralbee I'm not sure why you're taking someone referring to a group of people that they don't belong to as "them" as offensive. I'm White, so of course I would refer to Black people as "them" rather than "us". The New York Times updated their style guide after consulting their Black staff members.